# import data from csv file in my sql via php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I am trying to import data from csv file, which has the following format:

```
173,antony,xds1079,Antony,Pran,Pran Antony,,452522252,,,,antpran@hotmail.com,,,,,Yes,Yes,No,pricelist.xls
18,john,smithison22,John,Smith,Smith Jon,,545455726,,,,johnsmith01@in.com,,,,,Yes,Yes,No,pricelist.xls
22,nikolas,Brand44eBerg,Nikolas,Brandeberg,Brandeberg and sons ,,454554552,,,,brand88@freemail.co.uk,,,,,Yes,Yes,No,pricelist.xls
```

When inserted it in mySQL, the last field in the first row, contained *both* `pricelist.xls` and `18`. But the `18` should go in the next row, since it is the id field.

Here is the php code that I used:

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");


//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers_tmp (id,username, password, firstname, lastname, companyname, companyposition, phone1, phone2, mobilephone, fax, email, address, afm, doy, website, active, wholesaling , wholesaling_bulk , pricecatalog) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                '".addslashes($data[10])."',
                '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                '".addslashes($data[12])."',
                '".addslashes($data[13])."',
                '".addslashes($data[14])."',
                '".addslashes($data[15])."',
                '".addslashes($data[16])."',
                '".addslashes($data[17])."',
                '".addslashes($data[18])."',
                '".addslashes($data[19])."'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
//

//redirect
header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;
```

}

Does anyone know what I should do so the id can go in next line and not in the last field?

Comment: You can do this using pure SQL. Do you need to use PHP for any other reason with this? You could still make the file dynamic i.e the User could specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that someone else may need this solution, here is how I solved my problem:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Regards,Zoran